# ERROR RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded at Object.getApps

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase

I was trying to filter list of titles using Ng2SearchPipeModule. I have imported this module in app.module.ts and then generated new searchbar component

searchbar.component.ts

```
import { FirebaseService } from './../../firebase.service';
import { AngularFirestore } from '@angular/fire/firestore';
import { Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-searchbar',
  templateUrl: './searchbar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./searchbar.component.css']
})

export class SearchbarComponent implements OnInit{
constructor(private fireService:FirebaseService){}

titles:Array<any>;
  InputText:string;
  ngOnInit(){
    this.gettitles();
  }

  gettitles(){
    this.fireService.read_titles().subscribe(result =>{
      this.titles = result;
      console.log(this.titles);
    })
  }
}
```

And my searchbar.component.html looks like this

```
  <div class="search-field">
    <mat-form-field>
      <mat-label>Search</mat-label>
      <input id="input" type="text" matInput placeholder="" autocomplete="off" [(ngModel)]=InputText>
      <div><i class="fas fa-search"></i></div>
    </mat-form-field>
  </div>

  <div class="SearchTitles">
    <tbody>
      <tr *ngFor="let title of titles | filter:InputText">
        <td>{{title.payload.doc.data().title}}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </div>
```

I get correct output from my Firebase Firestore.
But Whenever I type any key on the input element I get this error **(I have entered 7 characters and I am getting this error 7 times)** and also filtering does not happen

[image: 1]

It seems this error is due to filer Module. I could get any info about how to fix this error...

Thank you for your Answer

Comment: you are updating same titles in the component?

Comment: you are updating title in component anywhere?

Comment: can you share the code in this.fireService.read_titles() because I think this function should return titles isstead of references to firebase documents.

Comment: Please check my new answer, let me know if you still agree

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is that your titles aren't a array of strings.
Change the title array to an array of strings:

The function in the service could return actual titles:

SERVICE

```
constructor(private afs: AngularFirestore) { }

read_titles() {
    return this.afs.collection<{title: string}>('here-your-table').valueChanges().pipe(
        map(list => list.map(v => v.title))
    )
}
```

TS of your component:

```
  gettitles(){
    this.fireService.read_titles()
  }
```

And in your html:

```
  <tr *ngFor="let title of titles | async | filter:InputText">
    <td>{{title}}</td>
  </tr>
```